# Error 1030 when I try to modify a Smartsheet

Tags: php, smartsheet-api, smartsheet-api-1.1

I have a php page that lists the smartsheet content for different users.
It populates a table with information like the name of a job, the start date and delivery date. But I would also like the users to be able to tick a checkbox when the job is done.

When the checkbox is checked another (very rudimentary) page is called to store the new value to the smartsheet.

This page is triggered by a basic get command like this:

http://myurl/index.php?colId=XXX&rowId=YYY&status=checked

Where the variables used are:

```
colId=The ID of the column to be changed
rowId=The ID of the row to be changed
checked=If the checkbox is checked
status=The value stored in the smartheet 
       (1 for a checked checkbox and '' for an unchecked checkbox)
```

This is the code of index.php (stolen from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24365644/update-cells-in-smartsheet)):

```
$inputToken = "myInputToken";
$colId=$_GET['colId'];
$rowId=$_GET['rowId'];
if($_GET['status'] == "checked"){
               $status='1';
               }
else{
               $status='';
}
$ch = curl_init("https://api.smartsheet.com/1.1/row/".$rowId./cells");
$header = array("Authorization: Bearer ".$inputToken,
        "Content-Type: application/json",
        "Assume-User: myName%40myDomainName");
$fields =  '[{"columnId": $colId, "value": "'.$status.'", "displayValue": "'.$status.'"}]';
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,  $fields);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "PUT");
$result = curl_exec($ch);
print_r($result);
```

The "input token" is generated by the same email that is used as the "Assume-User" email.
And I'm able to change the values in a regular smartsheet when I'm logged in.
But still I get this error when I run the webpage:

```
{"errorCode":1030,"message":"You are unable to assume the user specified."}
```

Does anyone know what I have done wrong?

Any help will be very appreciated!

Comment: The `$inputToken` needs to be a token that is generated by an administrator account. Then the `Assume-User` is the email address that you want to login as. Is that how you did it? If you have access to all of the accounts you can also generate a `$inputToken` for each account and remove the `Assume-User` line.

Comment: Thanks for the reply!
Unfortunatly I don't have access to the administrator account at the moment. But I'll give it a shot tomorrow when my  co workers are back again. I'll keep you posted!

Comment: Sounds like that is the issue as assume-user is intended for the admin account. I'll post my comment as the answer.

Comment: I just wanted to say that it worked with a token by an admin user.
Thank you so much for your invaluable help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two ways to login as a user. First you can login directly by using the token for that users account. The headers would look like:

```
$header = array('Authorization: Bearer '.$userToken,
    "Content-Type: application/json");
```

The second option is to use an administrator account to login as another user. To do this you can use the assume-user header along with the administrator's token. The headers would look like:

```
$header = array('Authorization: Bearer '.$adminToken,
    'Content-Type: application/json',
    'Assume-User: someUser%40someDomain.com');
```

The documentation for the assume-user can be found [here](http://www.smartsheet.com/developers/api-documentation#h.4t3dm23g377c).